# How do I make an exe into a service on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I recently made an application that has multiple parts. One of the parts is a networking tool - it always starts with the OS, and it never displays any sort of message. It does, however, start an incredibly irritating console, which is impossible to get rid of without closing the program itself (please just accept this one as given). I have decided to work around this problem by starting the program (it's a `*.exe`) as a service, thus stopping it from showing up at all. As the application will be distributed to various computers (hence the need for a networking tool in the first place). I need a way to make this program install as a service (so, I don't really want answers that tell me to go through a series of menus on the Control Panel or download a 3rd-party application that has to stay on whichever computer the service will run on). How can I do this?

Comment: You can't just take an exe and run it as a service.  It has to implement the interface that the Windows service manager expects.  You'll have to recode your application or else use a third party application.  Try doing a search for creating a Windows service using whatever development environment you used to create the exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Windows NT Resource Kit, Microsoft provides a tool called `srvany` that will run an `.exe` as a service.  A tool that works better than that is The [Non-Sucking Service Manager (nssm)](http://nssm.cc/).

I have used nssm to turn a python console executable that's a web server into a service that runs when the system boots successfully.

Comment: And this is OK to use? I would assume I have to include NSSM in the installer package and install as a service from there, so I'd just like to make sure that the author doesn't care. I would assume not, since there's no EULA...

Comment: I would reach out to the author for commercial redistribution rights if that's what you mean, I've only used it for personal use.  I just noticed in your question you said you wanted something without a 3rd party program involved but that's not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, fair enough. This is by far the best option I've come across so far...

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has compiled the steps to create a Windows Service and install it on a remote computer at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are too many step to outline here. There are additional links to assist you with potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third-party tools to run a normal Windows executable as a service.

Bitsum authored such a utility, command line only, called [MakeService](https://bitsum.com/other/) (now in limited distribution due to abuse).

It does this by using a service stub that then launches the normal Windows executable. That service stub can then control the launched process in response to service commands such as start, stop and pause.

However, if your application has any interactivity with the user, then you will encounter system service session isolation in NT6+.

Although we had to discontinue this freeware utility, we will still distribute it to those who have a legitimate need for it.

I am sure there are other similar utilities, including Microsoft's srvany.exe in the Windows Resource Kit, as the accepted answer recommends. It does the same thing as our MakeService did/does.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience NSSM is the best tool for this purpose. Firstly it's open source and secondly it support all versions of Windows. Another good thing about this tool is that is monitors the service, if it fails it restarts the service automatically. [Here's](https://www.helpmegeek.com/run-applications-as-windows-service/) a detailed guide on how to use it.

Comment: I've done this before with an exe using `sc` the built-in Windows tool too.